# Does spring boot takes enums as an integer

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, enums, entity

This is my Entity Role class

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column()
    private RoleName roleName;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return roleName.name();
    }
}
```

And this is my RoleName class

```
public enum RoleName {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_DIRECTOR
}
```

If I look at the database I see that type of role_name column is integer????
And when I'm writhing a query

```
insert into role(id, role_name)
values(1, 'ROLE_USER'),
      (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
      (3, 'ROLE_DIRECTOR');
```

it's giving me error message "invalid syntax for type integer: "ROLE_USER"
Can you help me how I can solve this issue and why role_name column is an integer when I give its type enum
This is an error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/dadab/IdeaProjects/app-email-auditing/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into role(id, role_name) values(1, 'ROLE_USER'), (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN'), (3, 'ROLE_DIRECTOR'); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "ROLE_USER"
  Позиция: 43
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.appemailauditing.AppEmailAuditingApplication.main(AppEmailAuditingApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/dadab/IdeaProjects/app-email-auditing/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into role(id, role_name) values(1, 'ROLE_USER'), (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN'), (3, 'ROLE_DIRECTOR'); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "ROLE_USER"
  Позиция: 43
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "ROLE_USER"
  Позиция: 43
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I have tried giving query with double quote

```
insert into role(id, role_name)
values(1, "ROLE_USER"),
      (2, "ROLE_ADMIN"),
      (3, "ROLE_DIRECTOR");
```

but it gave another error message " column 'ROLE_USER' does not exist "

I'm expectiong a reson why role_name is integer and how to give a column typa an enum

Answer (score 0):

Your `role_name` is an integer because you didn't create it to be a string.

If you want your enum value in your database to be a string you have to add this annotation to your field

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column
private RoleName roleName;
```

check this link for more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Changing below three steps to resolve

**Change your database**

```
ALTER TABLE role MODIFY COLUMN role_name ENUM('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_DIRECTOR');
```

**and then try to insert into database**

```
INSERT INTO role(id, role_name)   
VALUES (1,'ROLE_USER'),(2, 'ROLE_ADMIN', 3),(3, 'ROLE_DIRECTOR');
```

**and last but not the least, change your entity column**

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="role_name")
private RoleName roleName;
```